$\mathcal{F}{\left( \int _{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f \, dx \right)}=\int _{\epsilon}^{R}\widehat{Q_{t}^{2}f} \, dx$?
Let $\psi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ be radial, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \psi(x) \, dx =0$, $\int _{0}^{\infty}|\hat{\psi}(t)|^{2}  \frac{1}{t} \, dt = 1$. Define $Q_{t}f(x)=\psi_{t} * f(x)=t^{-n}\psi(t^{-1}(x)) * f(x)$

For $f\in L^{2}$, Why would we have $\mathcal{F}{\left( \int _{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f \, dx \right)}=\int _{\epsilon}^{R}\widehat{Q_{t}^{2}f} \, dx$? $Q_{t}^{2}f := \psi_{t}*\psi_{t}*f$. and the symbol $\mathcal{F}$ means the same as a widehat, which is fourier transform

I think this is true for $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ by using fubini theorem. However, I'm not sure if we can do the same when $f$ is in $L^{2}$ as then $Q_{t}^{2}f$ might no longer be in $L^{1}$.
Alternatively maybe one needs some other tricks, but I'm not sure what exactly to use. Perhaps argue by $S(R^{n})$ is dense in $L^{2}$

$Theorem$: Let $\psi \in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ be radial, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\psi(x)dx=0$, and $\int_{0}^{\infty}|\hat{\psi}(t)|^{2}\frac{1}{t}dt=1$. Define $Q_{t}f(x)=\psi_{t}*f(x)=t^{-n}\psi(t^{-1}(x))*f(x)$. Then for $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we have
$\mathcal{F}(\int_{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f~dx)=\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\hat{Q_{t}^{2}f}~dx$
Proof:
The Schwartz space $S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. This means that for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, there exists a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $f_n \to f \in L^2$ as $n \to \infty$.
The Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the product of their Fourier transforms. That is,
$\mathcal{F}(f*g) = \hat{f} \cdot \hat{g}$.
Fubini's theorem allows us to interchange the order of integration under certain conditions. In this case, we can use Fubini's theorem to interchange the order of integration in the integral $\int_{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f~dx$.
The Fourier transform is a continuous linear operator from $S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to $S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. This means that if $f_n \to f \in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then $\hat{f_n} \to \hat{f} \in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n \to f$ \in $L^2$ as $n \to \infty$.
For each n, we have
$\mathcal{F}(\int_{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f_n~dx)=\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\hat{Q_{t}^{2}f_n}~dx$
by Fubini's theorem and the Fourier transform of convolution.
Then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we get
$\mathcal{F}(\int_{\epsilon}^{R}Q_{t}^{2}f~dx)=\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\hat{Q_{t}^{2}f}~dx$
since the Fourier transform is continuous and the integral is a continuous linear functional.
Therefore, the theorem holds for all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

